# Keyboard not closing after returning from email client

Tags: android, android-intent, android-softkeyboard

I have an Android app that share a list of grocery over email. I have a trouble in which after I sent the list by email client (could be exchange client or Gmail client), the keyboard will not close.

I have tried:

```
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTxt.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

and many other ways. If I check if the keyboard is open, it will return `false` since it is not the app that called the keyboard, but the email client.

I found a workaround including:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

then the app will force closing the keyboard, but will continue lagging every time I open the keyboard again.

With Samsung phone the problem exists only if I use Gmail client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. After some millisecond, the focus changed from outside the app (Email-client) to the editText view. Then I can close the keyboard. 
So my solution looks like this:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                closeKeyboard();
            }
        }, 20);
```

Comment: No clearer way to know exactly when, I suppose. Even by polling, right? Tried to stick my nose into the input method service methods and data structures' fields but failed to find anything related to current focus.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"` in the activiy tag of your manifest

Comment: u mentioned that u used stateAlwaysHidden ... instead of this use stateHidden. it works for me for the similar cases

Comment: Sorry my fault, I mention stateAlwaysHidden because just as a workaround of closing the keyboard when returning from an intent.

Answer (score 0):

Do you put this code in the **onResume()** method ?

Comment: I use `startActivityForResult()`for fire the intent, so I have the code inside `onActivityResult`. But I will try to put it on onResume() method, is worth a shot.

Comment: I tried to put it on onResume(), but the problem is that the app not recognize that the keyboard is open, since the app didn't call to opened the keyboard. So the keyboard is not focused on the editTxt, and therefor I cant close it.

I have also tried `InputMethodManager im = (InputMethodManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  im.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);`

Comment: You can make a trick with booleans... Try to put a boolean in this activity. When you come from another activity of your application, put on the onCreate() method this boolean TRUE... When you come from the email client, don't instanciate this boolean (or = FALSE) and the condition to hide the keyboard is when this boolean = FALSE